# What syntax is represented by an ExtSlice node in Python's AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, internals

I'm wading through Python's `ast` module and can't figure out the slices definition:

```
slice = Ellipsis | Slice(expr? lower, expr? upper, expr? step) 
                 | ExtSlice(slice* dims) 
                 | Index(expr value)
```

So far, I know that `Ellipsis` is `[...]`, `Slice` is the usual `[start:end:step]` notation, `Index` is `[index]`, but which notation is `ExtSlice`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extended slice is a slice with multiple parts which uses some slice-specific feature.

A slice specific feature is something like `...` (a literal ellipsis) or a `:` (a test separator).

So, an example where `ExtSlice` is involved for an expression like `o[...:None]` or `o[1,2:3]`.

Here are some examples demonstrating this:

```
>>> compile('o[x]', '<string>', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST).body[0].value.slice
<_ast.Index object at 0xb72a9e6c>
>>> compile('o[x,y]', '<string>', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST).body[0].value.slice
<_ast.Index object at 0xb72a9dac>
>>> compile('o[x:y]', '<string>', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST).body[0].value.slice
<_ast.Slice object at 0xb72a9dcc>
>>> compile('o[x:y,z]', '<string>', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST).body[0].value.slice
<_ast.ExtSlice object at 0xb72a9f0c>
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! The documentation fails to deliver this description properly.

Comment: Can you **do** anything with an `ast.ExtSlice`? Is it *functional*?