# When to use ExtSlice node in Python's AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, internals

[Green Tree Snakes](http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) gives [an example](http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html?highlight=subscript#ExtSlice) of using `ExtSlice`:

```
>>> parseprint("l[1:2, 3]")
Module(body=[
    Expr(value=Subscript(value=Name(id='l', ctx=Load()), slice=ExtSlice(dims=[
        Slice(lower=Num(n=1), upper=Num(n=2), step=None),
        Index(value=Num(n=3)),
      ]), ctx=Load())),
  ])
```

However this syntax won't work in interactive python shell:

```
>>> foo = range(10)
>>> foo[1:2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Anyone got an idea how to use this feature?

Related discussion:

- [What syntax is represented by an ExtSlice node in Python's AST?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370643/2160440)

Comment: What do you expect `foo[1:2,3]` to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *syntax* works fine in the shell, it is just that *`list` objects* don't support extended slicing. What you tried raised a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Many [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array types do; that project was instrumental in driving the extended slicing syntax. Numpy arrays use extended slicing to address the different dimensions of multi-dimensional arrays. See the [Numpy *Indexing* chapter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html) for details on how they use the syntax.

Extended slicing is [explicitly documented in the *Subscription* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings), the AST nodes encode the `extended_slicing` term:

```
extended_slicing ::=  primary "[" slice_list "]"
slice_list       ::=  slice_item ("," slice_item)* [","]
slice_item       ::=  expression | proper_slice | ellipsis
proper_slice     ::=  short_slice | long_slice
```

There are no types in the Python standard library itself that make use of extended slicing, however.

You can easily build your own class to accept an extended slice; just expect to handle a tuple in your [`object.__getitem__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) implementation:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return item
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo[1, 2:3]
(1, slice(2, 3, None))
```

Each element of the `slice_list` becomes an object in a tuple, with `:`-separated slice indices passed in as `slice()` instances.