# Implementing a nested or multidimensional python list extended slicing

Tags: python

I want to implement a multidimentional list slicing. I call it `part` like similar built-in function of Mathematica's `Part`.

What I got so far is below definition.

```
class slicee:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item

def part(x,sliceList): 
    if len(sliceList)==1:
        return x[sliceList[0]]
    else:
        if type(sliceList[0])==slice:
            tmp=x[sliceList[0]]
        else:
            tmp=[x[sliceList[0]]]
        return [part(i,sliceList[1:]) for i in tmp]
```

Now we use this `part`. Define a nested list(just for convinience, I use all numbers, which I know numpy can slice it perfectly. But it just serves an example.)

```
     l=[[[8, 9, 5, 5], [2, 0, 3, 4], [1, 1, 6, 6], [3, 9, 9, 3]],
 [[3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 1, 0, 2], [8, 2, 9, 5], [3, 5, 6, 8]],
 [[3, 5, 7, 2], [7, 2, 3, 9], [2, 1, 5, 2], [7, 6, 2, 2]],
 [[3, 0, 8, 3], [3, 7, 8, 1], [9, 4, 7, 2], [2, 0, 5, 7]]]
```

and

```
part(l,slicee()[:,:,0])
```

gives

```
[[8, 2, 1, 3], [3, 3, 8, 3], [3, 7, 2, 7], [3, 3, 9, 2]]
```

This is quite good except that I don't like the interface which have to explicitly write `slicee()`

**Is it possible to make the interface of `part` to be `part(l,[:,:,0])` or even better `part(l,:,:,0)`? Or is there already some package deal with this general slicing?**

Comment: Adding `print(f'{sliceList}')` to the top of `part` gives some clues. Using `(x,*args*)` for the call signature will also help.

Comment: Fails with `part(a,slicee()[1,:,0])`.

Comment: Are you doing this for learning/educational purposes, or to actually use?

Comment: @wwii Thank you for point out my bug. I updated my post to fix it. But what do you mean by `Using (x,*args*)`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC Of course for actual use. I am exploring the possiblity of realizing the convinience functional programming like Mathematica so that I could switch these two languages freely. Currently, python seems awkard to use for me for functional programming, and lack of `part` is just one aspect.

Comment: _Of course for actual use._ Then you should probably just use NumPy. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _convinience functional programming like Mathematica_, can you explain it further? _Currently, python seems awkard to use for me for functional programming_ Indeed, the support for functional programming in Python is quite limited.

Comment: Also, do note that generally variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and class names the `CapWords` style.

Comment: @AMC Hi, AMC. Of course I know numpy well. But elements in numpy array is of same types. But the power of python list is that it can contain any object, and sometimes we need this kind of container and slice elements from it. Well, my post is just seeking a possiblity which I think it is possible. After all, numpy has great fancy index interface, I think they built it on top of python, right? I think we could also overloading bracket and colon like `python_list{:,:,1}` to fancy slcing python list.

Comment: _But elements in numpy array is of same types._ NumPy does have structured arrays though. _I think they built it on top of python, right?_ What do you mean? _But the power of python list is that it can contain any object, and sometimes we need this kind of container and slice elements from it._ Do you have any particular examples that you're dealing with?

Comment: Looks like `:` or `[:,:]` are only valid in a subscription of some sort. `def f(a):pass; f(:)` produces a syntax error. I can't find that explicitly in the docs. Your wish for a *cleaner* interface may not be possible.

Comment: Did you get your `slice` clas from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815405/2823755?

Comment: @AMC Thank you so much for your suggestion. Indeed, cases we need slicing multidimentional irregular list are rare. But have this tool in the tool bag is good :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I could get. Subclass `list` and override `__getitem__`.

```
class Foo(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        b = list(self)
        for thing in item:
            b = b[thing]
        return b

a = [[[8, 9, 5, 5], [2, 0, 3, 4], [1, 1, 6, 6], [3, 9, 9, 3]],
     [[3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 1, 0, 2], [8, 2, 9, 5], [3, 5, 6, 8]],
     [[3, 5, 7, 2], [7, 2, 3, 9], [2, 1, 5, 2], [7, 6, 2, 2]],
     [[3, 0, 8, 3], [3, 7, 8, 1], [9, 4, 7, 2], [2, 0, 5, 7]]]

>>> a = Foo(a)
>>> a[:,:,1]
[[3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 1, 0, 2], [8, 2, 9, 5], [3, 5, 6, 8]]
>>> a[:,1,1]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
>>> a[1,1,1]
1
>>>
```

---

Caveat: Did not assess unintended consequences.  Here are a couple...

```
>>> a[1,]
[[3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 1, 0, 2], [8, 2, 9, 5], [3, 5, 6, 8]]

>>> a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#458>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1]
  File "C:\pyProjects\tmp.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    for thing in item:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

>>> a[1,1,1,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#457>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1,1,1,1]
  File "C:\pyProjects\tmp.py", line 35, in __getitem__
    b = b[thing]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

---

In order to implement as a function with two arguments - `part(thelist,theslice)`. You would need to parse `theslice` argument and expand it to a tuple of slice objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for introduce this clever class approach! +1 But there are some bugs in you class. I made a self answer based on your approach, take a look at it :) I felt my function is too complex, maybe you have time to get a better one :)

Comment: @user15964 + oned your *self-answer* - nice

Answer (score 2):

Enlightened by wwii, I made below `part` class which fix some bugs in both wwii's answer and my post

```
class part(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        b=list(self)
        def part_internal(x,slice_spec): 
            if type(slice_spec)==tuple:
                if len(slice_spec)>1:
                    tmp=x[slice_spec[0]]
                    if type(slice_spec[0])==slice:
                        return [part_internal(i,slice_spec[1:]) for i in tmp]
                    else:
                        return part_internal(tmp,slice_spec[1:])
                else:
                    return x[slice_spec[0]]
            else:
                return x[slice_spec]
        return part_internal(b,item)
```

Define

```
l=[[[8, 9, 5, 5], [2, 0, 3, 4], [1, 1, 6, 6], [3, 9, 9, 3]],
 [[3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 1, 0, 2], [8, 2, 9, 5], [3, 5, 6, 8]],
 [[3, 5, 7, 2], [7, 2, 3, 9], [2, 1, 5, 2], [7, 6, 2, 2]],
 [[3, 0, 8, 3], [3, 7, 8, 1], [9, 4, 7, 2], [2, 0, 5, 7]]]
```

Now we have

```
print(part(l)[0])
print(part(l)[0,0])
print(part(l)[0,0,0])
print(part(l)[:,0])
print(part(l)[:,:,0])
print(part(l)[:,0:2,0:2])
```

gives

```
[[8, 9, 5, 5], [2, 0, 3, 4], [1, 1, 6, 6], [3, 9, 9, 3]]
[8, 9, 5, 5]
8
[[8, 9, 5, 5], [3, 4, 0, 2], [3, 5, 7, 2], [3, 0, 8, 3]]
[[8, 2, 1, 3], [3, 3, 8, 3], [3, 7, 2, 7], [3, 3, 9, 2]]
[[[8, 9], [2, 0]], [[3, 4], [3, 1]], [[3, 5], [7, 2]], [[3, 0], [3, 7]]]
```